# WIX: Property value doesn't change from Publish element

Tags: deployment, wix, wix3.7

I have created the following property:

```
<Property Id="InstallationType" Value="InstallComplete" ></Property>
```

I tried to change this property value according do button clicked in the UI:

```
<Control Id="TypicalButton" Type="PushButton" X="40" Y="65" Width="100" Height="37" ToolTip="!(loc.SetupTypeDlgTypicalButtonTooltip)" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.SetupTypeDlgTypicalButton)" IconSize="48" Property="InstallationType">
   <Publish Property="WixUI_InstallMode" Value="InstallTypical">1</Publish>
   <Publish Property="InstallationType" Value="InstallTypical" >1</Publish>
   <Publish Event="SetInstallLevel" Value="1">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

And then to include a feature depends on the property value:

```
<Feature Id="test" Title="test" Level="0" >
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="CompilationHeadset" />
  <Condition Level="1">InstallationType="InstallTypical"</Condition>
</Feature>
```

The problem is that when I click the "TypicalButton" it doesn't include the feature so I'm understand for it that the condition is false because the property value doesn't changed as it should be.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Bob Arnson answered this thoroughly in his blog post [Feature conditions and UI](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2007/05/30/feature-conditions-and-ui/). The TLDR: [Publish](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/publish.html) ADDLOCAL and REMOVE events instead of setting properties in an attempt to influence [Feature/Condition](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/condition.html)s that were already evaluated.